# SubForm control without its own form (Source object not a form but a table). How to set event handlers?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In a main-form I am programmatically creating subform controls that have tables as their SourceObject.

```
Dim frmNew As SubForm

Set frmNew = CreateControl("01_MAIN_FORM", acSubform, acDetail, strTabDesired, , 200, nBottom + 500, 20000, 3000)

frmNew.Name = "SomeName" 
frmNew.SourceObject = "Table.SomeTable"
```

My problem is: In the container I can only access the OnEnter and OnExit events of the subform.

I want to handle the AfterUpdate-Event.
If I would use a Form as the SourceObject of the Subform-Control, I could handle it there.
But actually I want to avoid creating a lot of Forms just in order to link them later in the main-form.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually refer to the subforms events over the "Form" property.
In my case

```
Application.Forms("01_MAIN_FORM").Form("SomeName").Form.AfterUpdate = "SomeMacro"
```

Just make sure that the form that contains the subform controls actally is opened in form view, so you have a valid reference to the form object.